# Background message handler on iOS release mode not called when app is in the background [FCM, Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

My background message handler for FCM is not being called on iOS.

I have followed the steps [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration) in setting up for ios FCM.

I have also toggle on and check Background fetch and Remote Notifications respectively as shown

[image]

FCM messages with notification or notification + data work fine.

However, when I use data-only messages for triggering the background message handler, the handler is not triggered.

Below is my code:

```
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
      print(message.data);
   
    }
    
    
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
      setupDependencies();
      runApp(MyApp());
      }
```

Below is the data I sent from postman to test the background handler:

```
{
    "content_available" : true,
    "priority" : "high",
   "data" : {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "x": "22",
   },
    "to":"xxxUSER_FCM_TOKENxxx"
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Try `content-available: 1` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: I tried that but it says "Field "content_available" must be a JSON boolean: 1"

Comment: Ok, maybe FCM translates it before it sends it to APNS.

Comment: yes, I think so too. What else do you think can be causing this issue?

Comment: The weird part is, it works sometimes when I'm using the debug version but doesn't work on my release app.